# Extracting words from a website

Tags: android

Hi I want to try making a simple application for android phones for which I will be requiring a dictionary. I thought of using urbandictionary.com as the reference site. Is there any technique by which I can extract all the words with the definitions and their respective words in the thesaurus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking out the Google example found at

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

It appears that they just add their words with this example

```
        private void loadWords() throws IOException {
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
        final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "-");
                if (strings.length < 2) continue;
                long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                if (id < 0) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
    }
```

However, when I look for R.raw.definitions that directory is empty.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/res/raw/index.html